# how to make a jar file always running

Tags: java, linux

i have a jar file: myServerSide.jar,
this jar takes request from client apps, processes them, each one ina thread and renders a response
i've put my jar on linux, but i want it to be ALWAYS running

if i do `java -jar myServerSide.jar &` for no reason it stops after a while

i also tried `deamon -- java -jar myServerSide.jar &` it also stops

do you know the reason why?

what should i do,so that it stays always running, and never exit.(is it necessary to make it a service)
thanks for your help
(i'm hosting my jar on linode (a VPS) if it is related)

this is the code for my server

```
        try
    {

        FTLogger.getInstance().logMessage(Level.FINE, "S: Connecting...");

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        while (true)
        {
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread(client));
            serverThread.start();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FTLogger.getInstance().logMessage(Level.SEVERE, "S: Error getting connection", e);
    }
```

in my logs, i don't see any error, and when working the jar works as it should.
(if you're sure that it's smthg from my code, should i open another question, and discard this?)

Comment: does it have execution permission ?

Comment: If the programme terminates unpredictably, this will be for a specific reason, you need to investigate this. I imagine it's a bug in your code. Get your application to record a log and catch all exceptions.

Comment: no no , no error occurs, i log my errors, and catch exceptions

Comment: Did you try it with a root user ? Does it start and accept a connection at all ? The user you're starting it with might not have needed socket permissions. The code you posted definitely shouldn't stop unless killed. I'd still recommend debugging it, but it looks like its not a problem in the code. Its probably permissions.

Comment: yes i call as root, and the socket works, i test from clients and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have access to screen you can try nohup java -jar myServerSide.jar > log.out &

Comment: I was asusming you were closing the terminal after running the command. Doing so sends the interrupt or kill switch not sure which, but basically doing & doesn't actually mean it will run when the console is closed. The best way is to use screen, but nohup is a nice quick way to achieve background process running as well

Answer (score 3):

> if i do java -jar myServerSide.jar & for no reason it stops after a while

The reason it stops could be (probably is) in your code.

Debugging it should tell you why it stops.

Comment: +1 - Investigate what is causing the problem.  Cure the disease not the symptom.

Answer (score 2):

If an java.lang.Error occurs it wouldn't be catched by

```
 catch (Exception e) {
 ...
 }
```

only

```
 catch( Throwable t ) {
 ...
 }
```

would do it.

Comment: hi, i changed all my exception handling to throwable, and still nothing shows, anything else i can try?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should ensure this programatically by something like infinite loop waiting for requests from client and delegating them to separate threads for processing:

```
// this is very high-level and obviously a exit point from this loop should be provided
while (true) {
    Request r = waitForRequest();
    processRequestInNewThread(r);
}
```

Or is there something more you need that I'm missing? Maybe a sample code from your implementation of request handling will help.

Comment: yes, this is exactly how i'm doing it, are you sure that it's something in my code, so this is where i should be searching?

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, there could be quite a few reasons. E.g. do you know whether your application process any request?

Comment: yes yes it does, the app works fine, when testing from the client, this is how i proceed, i launch the call from putty ,i test from my client, everything works fine, after a couple of hours, i retest and it tells me that it cannot connect to the jar, i reopen putty, check ps -ef | grep myserver.. and i can't find the process

Comment: That very weird. What else you can try is to take a look at the process footprint to see whether there is e.g. some memory leak that might be indirectly causing the jar to be killed. And even more, does it reply to multiple request before it eventually dies? I mean, is it like it runs for hours, answering the request and from all the sudden it dies for now obvious reason?

Answer (score 0):

You should give us some code. The first thing that pops into my mind is that you need to make sure your method that accepts the connections from clients need to run in an infinite loop. For example:

```
while (true) {
    acceptAndParseRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you launch a java application, and you embed your code into a loop:

```
while(true){
...
}
```

It will never stop, the only reason why it should stop it's because an exception is launched (do you consume resources inside the while) ?
In case it really stops, try to understand what is the problem in this way:

```
while(true){
  try{
     ... your code ....
     }catch(Throwable t){
      system.out.println("This is my problem:" + t.printStackTrace);
     }
}
```

Sure it helps